# How can I code a success page for my login and register page?

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so. I am coding a website for a project and I have a login and register page. I would like to figure out how to code a success page for them and if anyone has the time a failure page. The success page should redirect to the index.html and the failure page should put them back to the same page to try again (but with an error message).
First is signin.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sign-In!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style2.css?q={{time}}" type="text/css">
    <form action="/register">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="reg">

<form>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR EMAIL</p>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</p>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Next is register.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Register!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style2.css?q={{time}}" type="text/css">
    <form action="/register">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="reg">

<form>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR EMAIL</p>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR NAME</p>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">ENTER YOUR PASSWORD</p>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Next here are the current app routes I have for them.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('register.html', time=datetime.now())
    else:
        print("eek")


@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('/signin.html')
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Hey Chelsea, I think you have more of a request than a question and should try to code it on your own first. But as a starting point, you need to define the javascript methods for handling log in and register events, create functions in your backend (where your routes are written) for handling those events, process them in frontend with javascript and after that redirect to an index or other page.

Comment: I tried to but I couldn't' really figure it out. I'm very much a beginner of coding. Only been coding about two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

View it this way:

1. Have a flask route that authenticates submitted login credentials, this should be called by you login button. Then, add your conditions, just like:

   ```
      @app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
      @app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
      def signin():
          #authentication line goes here (you may a function function you already written for this purpose here
          if authentication == True:
              return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))#user is redirected to welcome page
          else:
              return redirect(url_for('loginpage'))#user is redirected to login page with error message
   ```

Comment: You may use flash message to output errors or success messages